# How can i set selected value after submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html-select, reload

I have a form with month and year to select. I want to save selected values after page reload. I have project in django and i don't have any idea how  do it.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="show_incomes">{% csrf_token %}{{form}}
 <div class="form-group ">

  <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="miesiac">Wybierz miesiąc</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
   <select class="select form-control" id="miesiac" name="miesiac">
    <option value="01" >Styczeń</option>
    <option value="02" >Luty</option>
    <option value="03" >Marzec</option>
    <option value="04" >Kwiecień</option>
    <option value="05" >Maj</option>
    <option value="06" >Czerwiec</option>
    <option value="07" >Lipiec</option>
    <option value="08" >Sierpień</option>
    <option value="09" >Wrzesień</option>
    <option value="10" >Październik</option>
    <option value="11" >Listopad</option>
    <option value="12" >Grudzień</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
<label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="rok">Wybierz rok</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
   <select class="select form-control" id="rok" name="rok" >
    <option value="2017" >2017</option>
    <option value="2018" >2018</option>
    <option value="2019" >2019</option>
    <option value="2020" >2020</option>
    <option value="2021" >2021</option>
    <option value="2022" >2022</option>
    <option value="2023" >2023</option>
    <option value="2024" >2024</option>
    <option value="2025" >2025</option>
   </select><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-info">Pokaż    przychody</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: use localstorage

Comment: where you want to save the value?localstorage?

Comment: thanks, localstorage will be ok

Comment: i suggest use ajax request.. read on ajax

Comment: @RobertKulicki. If you are satisfied with the answer, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Maybe somebody will add some pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local storage/ session storage to save data

Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)